# convert a string in order to access the dom elements of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, svg, xmlhttprequest

I have a string which contains my response.

```
var c = atob(btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(event.getParameter('response')))));
```

this returns the elements of the document in a string format.

I want to access the svg element that is inside this response

[image]

How can I convert the string in order to access the elements inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could insert the string you get into a hidden element, and append them into the body of the document. Then retrieve the element you want via proper selectors:

```js
var elemString = '<div id="yourElement">My element</div>';

$('body').append('<span id="test" style="display:none">' + elemString + '</span>');
alert($('#test').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply kapantzak. I tried to append it to my object. it gets attached as a string to the "inner html" so when i do $('object).append(my string); in the console it gives me a function (object) when i expand it i see that inner and outer html have the string with the elements. how can i access the innerhtml to get the svg height and width?

Comment: var h = f.getParameter('response');
                var c = atob(btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null , new Uint8Array(f.getParameter('response')))));
                this._svg = document.createElement('object');
                this._svg.setAttribute('type', 'image/svg+xml');
                this._svg.setAttribute('data', c);
                this._svg.setAttribute('id', this._svgid);
                this._svg.setAttribute('class', 'SVGImage');
                this._canvas.appendChild(this._svg); this appends the code to the object

Comment: . it looks right from the "Elements" view in the console but it doesnt render the image. i get a 404 in the console saying: GET http://localhost:8089%3C?xml%20version=…Crect%20x=%220%22%20y=%220%22%20width=%2250%22%20height=%221%22%20fill=%22 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1):

Use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to convert the string to a document

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(stringContainingXMLSource, "application/xml");
```

then you can use DOM on the document. Unless you need to use some method that requires layout you don't need to add it to your existing document.

If you wanted the width of value of the `<svg>` element you could write

```
width = doc.documentElement.getAttribute('width');
```

If you want to render it you'd just attach it to the document e.g.

```
element.appendChild(doc.documentElement)
```

where element was some element in your existing document.